# Java full screen exclusive mode

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fullscreen, joptionpane

I made my application to be full screen in exclusive mode but when I show an input dialog the application is minimized. I want the application to stay full screen and the input dialog to be show over it.

This is how I render my application full screen:

```
setUndecorated(true);
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gs = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
gs.setFullScreenWindow(this);
validate();
```

**Edit:**

This is how I open the dialog:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(StartingPoint.this,txt, "You are on: " + planet, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

Comment: what is your code for showing the input dialog ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

```
but when I show an input dialog the application is minimized
```

1) I can't to simulating this issue and simly isn't possible without additional code [iconofied](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowIconified%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) for [Full-Screen Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html)

2) please to check [Programming Tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html) about AWT/Swing

3) `setParent` (not possible corectly for `JFrame`) for `input dialog`

4) to check if isn't there more than one [Top-level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) with [setModal / ModalityTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29)