# Stop Fullscreen Window from minimizing when JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, swing, awt, fullscreen, java-2d

### The Code

```
private MainApp() /* Extends JFrame */{
    DisplayMode displayMode = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, 75);
    ScreenManager.setFullScreenWindow(displayMode, this);
}
```

### The Problem

Whenever I call:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainApp.getInstance(), "Test Message Box");
```

The Window minimizes for some reason, then I have to re-activate it. The Message Box shows after I re-activate the Window.

### The Question

Is there any way to stop the Fullscreen Window from minimizing when I call the Message Box?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: thanks, I made it concise. waiting for help now... :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142300/java-full-screen-exclusive-mode ??? I never see this lack maybe these issues have got an airport here

Comment: @IntermediateHacker please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142300/java-full-screen-exclusive-mode , before posting SSCCE here

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a modal dialog is displayed (JOptionPane, JFileChooser, etc.), the JFrame gets a WINDOW_DEACTIVATED WindowEvent.  Simply ignore the window deactivation when your app is displayed as fullscreen:

```
@Override
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e)
{
    if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_DEACTIVATED)
    {
        // windowState is set in my set full screen code
        if (windowState == WindowState.FULL_SCREEN)
        {
            return;
        }
    }        

    super.processWindowEvent(e);        
}
```

Be sure to set the parent of modal dialog correctly:

```
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
```

Where "this" is your top most JPanel, JInternalFrame, or JFrame.

Comment: Works perfectly! But I can't use/find the constant WindowState.FULL_SCREEN. Is it just available under Linux?