# JOptionPane minimizes fullscreen app

Tags: swing, awt, java-7, joptionpane

Have the same issue like mentioned here:
[Stop Fullscreen Window from minimizing when JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179493/stop-fullscreen-window-from-minimizing-when-joptionpane-showmessagedialog)
[Java full screen exclusive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142300/java-full-screen-exclusive-mode)

I am using a JDesktopPane and a JDialogPane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use the `showInternalOptionDialog` method applied to the JDialogPane, then it works
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html
http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JOptionPane-Display-Internal-Dialog-Box.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalOptionDialog